# "Sys is undefined" error because WebResource.axd is returning the wrong content

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting the dreaded "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Sys' is undefined" error while trying to develop a site in ASP.NET on .NET framework 4.0.  This was working fine until I tried programmatically adding items to a menu, and this started happening.  While debugging, I pointed Fiddler at my app and found that the request for the WebResource.axd is returning successfully (code == 200), but the response text is  *the whole html page* and **NOT** the javascript that it is supposed to be returning, and this is why Sys is undefined.

What's going on here?  Any help much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, thanks to [this](http://www.reddybrek.com/post/How-to-fix-WebResourceaxd-JavaScript-errors-appearing-when-using-aspnet-routing.aspx).  I'm using ASP.NET Routing, and I was routing root level requests like `http://www.mysite.com/{PageId}`, and this matching pattern is so general that it was also matching the request for `/WebResource.axd`, and that's why the page request for the axd file was being routed to an aspx page instead of the usual handler.  Not what I would have expected, but I can see the logic.

The fix is to tell the routing system to ignore this *particular* kind of request:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")
```